# How do I get the DNS Default Gateway IP on the active connection and set it to a variable using a Windows 10 Batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, dns

Here's the setup,

- **Primary DNS:** Variable, could be 192.168.1.1, 192.168.1.2 or
  192.168.1.3
- **Secondary DNS:** Static, 172.20.16.1

On Windows 10 machines, I want a startup script that finds the active connection (could jump between wireless and wired on docked laptops) and swaps the secondary DNS (172.20.16.1) with the Primary DNS (variable).

Here's where I'm at so far,

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
SET adapterName=
FOR /F "tokens=* delims=:" %%a IN ('IPCONFIG ^| FIND /I "ETHERNET ADAPTER"') DO (
SET adapterName=%%a
SET adapterName=!adapterName:~17!
SET adapterName=!adapterName:~0,-1!
FOR /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%g IN ('netsh interface ip show address "!adapterName!" ^| findstr "Default"') do 
set DefaultGateway=%%g
netsh interface ipv4 set dns name="!adapterName!" static 172.20.16.1 primary
netsh interface ipv4 add dns name="!adapterName!" !DefaultGateway! index=2
ipconfig /flushdns
:EOF
```

The part that isn't working is getting the Default Gateway,

```
FOR /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%g IN ('netsh interface ip show address "!adapterName!" ^| findstr "Default"') do 
set DefaultGateway=%%g
```

Not sure if this is the correct way to add a the "DefaultGateway" variable either,

```
netsh interface ipv4 add dns name="!adapterName!" !DefaultGateway! index=2
```

EDIT:

I was able to get the following to work. Will it work for both wireless and ethernet connections and/or are there other conceivable problem with this approach?

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
SET dgateway=
for /f "tokens=2,3 delims={,}" %%g in ('"WMIC NICConfig where IPEnabled="True" get DefaultIPGateway /value | find "I" "') do SET dgateway=%%~g
SET adapterName=
FOR /F "tokens=* delims=:" %%a IN ('IPCONFIG ^| FIND /I "ETHERNET ADAPTER"') DO (
SET adapterName=%%a
SET adapterName=!adapterName:~17!
SET adapterName=!adapterName:~0,-1!
netsh interface ipv4 set dns name="!adapterName!" static 172.20.16.1 primary
netsh interface ipv4 add dns name="!adapterName!" %dgateway% index=2
)
ipconfig /flushdns
:EOF
```

Comment: The two-line "part that isn't working" is supposed to be one line.

Comment: What did you mean by "DNS default gateway IP" ??

Comment: I have an assortment of physical networks at different locations and use a centralized cloud hosted Domain Controller for Windows authentication and group policy. With the exception of the Windows computers, everything else on the network only needs Internet access. So I have the local router handing out DHCP IP, subnet, and default gateway. I want to capture the default gateway address, as this is also the routers DNS address and on the Windows computers make the default gateway address the secondary DNS, so I can make the Domain Controller the default. I should have worded it better.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it but I'm open to ideas on how to make it better or if there are obvious flaws.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
SET dgateway=
for /f "tokens=2,3 delims={,}" %%g in ('"WMIC NICConfig where IPEnabled="True" get DefaultIPGateway /value | find "I" "') do SET dgateway=%%~g
SET iptrue=false
IF %dgateway%==192.168.1.1 SET iptrue=true
IF %dgateway%==192.168.2.1 SET iptrue=true
IF %dgateway%==192.168.3.1 SET iptrue=true
IF %iptrue%==true (
 SET adapterName=
 FOR /F "tokens=* delims=:" %%a IN ('IPCONFIG ^| FIND /I "ETHERNET ADAPTER"') DO (
  SET adapterName=%%a
  SET adapterName=!adapterName:~17!
  SET adapterName=!adapterName:~0,-1!
  netsh interface ipv4 set dns name="!adapterName!" static 172.20.16.1 primary
  netsh interface ipv4 add dns name="!adapterName!" %dgateway% index=2
 )
 ipconfig /flushdns
)
:EOF
```